# I want to apply a formula in R, multiply a value in one vector by that in another vector and so on

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a `complexity` vector with ratings from 1-9, and time `durations` for each complexity rating, I want to multiple the durations by the corresponding complexity score for that period and weight by the time duration, for example:

> subject S001, replicate 1, stimulus S1, "soft" attribute: 2*(0.99 - 0.77) / 0.99-0.77 = 2

then in an example where there is more than 1 complexity rating for,

> subject S001, replicate 2, stimulus S1, "soft" attribute: 2*(0.32-0.14)+1*(0.99-0.32)/(0.32-0.14)+(0.99-0.32) = 1.21

```
structure(list(Replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Stimulus = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Subject = c("S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", "S001", 
"S001", "S001", "S001", "S001"), Attribute = c("Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft", 
"Soft", "Soft", "Soft", "Soft"), Timepoint = c(0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 
0.8, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9, 
0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.19, 0.2, 
0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25), Dominant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Complexity = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), start_time = c(0.77, 
0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 
0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.24, 0.24), end_time = c(0.99, 
0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 
0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.99, 0.99), duration = c(0.22, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.75, 0.75), complexity_x_duration = c(NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.75, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(Replicate = 1:2, 
    Stimulus = c(1L, 1L), Subject = c("S001", "S001"), Attribute = c("Soft", 
    "Soft"), .rows = list(1:23, 24:30)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

My best attempt so far is below, but it returns only zeros. I feel I am going about this in a roundabout way and could maybe use a `forloop` to make it easier.

```
tds_merged_duration4<-modified_tds_merged %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute) %>% 
  mutate(duration = end_time - start_time) %>% 
  mutate(complexity_x_duration = ifelse(Complexity!=lag(Complexity, 1), duration*Complexity,0))
```

This is another attempt:

```
 for (i in 1:20614) {
    if (tds_merged_duration3$Complexity==lag(tds_merged_duration3$Complexity,1)){
      NA
    }else{
      (tds_merged_duration3$Complexity*tds_merged_duration3$duration)/tds_merged_duration3$duration
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has no problem; due to `Complexity` being equal to 2 for each row you will end up having `Complexity != lag(Complexity, 1)` equal to `FALSE` for each row and your `ifelse` will evaluate to 0 every time. `Duration`  also has the same value for each row. As a result, your expression in the last mutate will always evaluate to the same value. Are the values in your data correct?

Comment: The values change throughout the data set, but the zero's are still returned. `Complexity` is a rating between 1 and 9. 'Duration` is the time from `start_time` to `end_time`, so it's the duration of a complexity rating based on `stimulus` `subject` `replicate` or `attribute`.

Comment: can you add more data?

Comment: what code can I use to print more data?

Comment: try `dput(head(data, n))` and copy the result here. This will give us the first `n` lines of your data object. With n being large enough to contain the interesting data. E,g, `n = 25`

Comment: thank you. I edited the question with the data.

Comment: There are three change points in your extended data set: for lines 1, 24 and 29. Line 1 has to be NA as this is the first line of the data set and the `lag` function must return `NA`. At line 24, grouping variable `Replicate` changes and at line 29 variable `Complexity` changes. As a result of the grouping variable changing at line 24, the `lag` function returns `NA` as this is the first row of a new group. All calculations for `complexity_x_duration` appear as per your expression. No zeros are calculated. Are you certain there are no code errors which you have not shared here?

Comment: no code errors using that first code in my question. the `complexity_x_duration` column that is returned is all zero's with only a couple of random (as far as I can see) numbers, I want it to print the answer to `complexity`*`duration` if `complexity` rating changed, or if  `stimulus` `subject` `replicate`or `attribute` changed. Is there a problem with my lag function maybe?

Comment: your code executes correctly on my PC.

Comment: So you are getting a value in `complexity_x_duration` everytime the `complexity` `replicate` `attribute` `stimulus` or `subject` values change?

Comment: Yes, except off course when a grouping variable changes: the lag function then looks for the 'zero-est' line in the group and it returns `NA`, as it must. See my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of your code running on my PC with what appears to be a correctly calculated column `complexity_x_duration`:

```
> tail(tds_merged_duration4,20)
# A tibble: 20 x 11
# Groups:   Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute [2]
   Replicate Stimulus Subject Attribute Timepoint Dominant Complexity start_time end_time duration complexity_x_duration
       <int>    <int> <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>    <int>      <int>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>                 <dbl>
 1         1        1 S001    Soft           0.87        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 2         1        1 S001    Soft           0.88        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 3         1        1 S001    Soft           0.89        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 4         1        1 S001    Soft           0.9         1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 5         1        1 S001    Soft           0.91        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 6         1        1 S001    Soft           0.92        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 7         1        1 S001    Soft           0.93        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 8         1        1 S001    Soft           0.94        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
 9         1        1 S001    Soft           0.95        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
10         1        1 S001    Soft           0.96        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
11         1        1 S001    Soft           0.97        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
12         1        1 S001    Soft           0.98        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
13         1        1 S001    Soft           0.99        1          2       0.77     0.99    0.220                 0.440
14         2        1 S001    Soft           0.19        1          2       0.19     0.23    0.04                 NA    
15         2        1 S001    Soft           0.2         1          2       0.19     0.23    0.04                  0.08 
16         2        1 S001    Soft           0.21        1          2       0.19     0.23    0.04                  0.08 
17         2        1 S001    Soft           0.22        1          2       0.19     0.23    0.04                  0.08 
18         2        1 S001    Soft           0.23        1          2       0.19     0.23    0.04                  0.08 
19         2        1 S001    Soft           0.24        1          1       0.24     0.99    0.75                  0    
20         2        1 S001    Soft           0.25        1          1       0.24     0.99    0.75                  0.75
```

Comment: OK, I am thinking that if I change `digit =` for `complexity_x_duration` it will show as yours is, I'm just trying to figure out how to do that...

Comment: I can not figure out how to chnage the decimel point for  `complexity_x_duration`. `" "` is returned when I use `formatC(tds_merged_duration4$complexity_x_duration, digits = 3)` Can you advise?

Comment: `formatC(tds_merged_duration4$complexity_x_duration, 3)` returns `"  NA" "0.44" "0.44" "0.44" "0.44" "0.44"` for me.

Comment: `formatC(tds_merged_duration4$complexity_x_duration, 3)` returns this for me
   `[1] "  NA" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0"
  [10] "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0"
  [19] "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "  NA" "   0" "   0" "   0"
  [28] "   0" "   1" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0" "   0"` I am so lost!

Comment: I have now got 3 decimal places, but still many more zeros??`[1]   NA 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  [14] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00   NA 0.00 0.00
  [27] 0.00 0.00 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  [40] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
  [53] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00`

Comment: you should look at the code that calculates `tds_merged_duration4$complexity_x_duration`. `formatC` is not likely to turn your data into zeros.

Comment: I can get the same values as you by removing the `ifelse` portion of the code and simply using `complexity`*`duration`. But I only want to calculate `complexity`*`duration` if the complexity rating changes, as in my formula at the begining of my question. My main issue here is that I want to apply that formula to my data and I can't work out how to do that. I am looking for an easier method that my current process which is going through it step by step almost, as if in Excel.

Comment: It would, except for line 19 in my answer: the zero there for `complexity_x_duration` is caused by the `ifelse` evaluating to the `FALSE` condition.

Comment: OK yeah that makes sense. I didn't know how to write the ifelse to achieve what I want, maybe a forloop would work better? Any thoughts and ideas that you might have would be most welcome? I am still very new to R.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by removing the `ifelse` function

```
modified_tdc_merged<-tdc_merged.df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = as.numeric(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", Timepoint))) %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute, Complexity) %>% 
  summarise(
    start_time = min(Timepoint), 
    end_time = max(Timepoint),
    duration = end_time - start_time,
    n = n()
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

tdc_cwd_score.df <- modified_tdc_merged %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject, Attribute) %>% 
  summarise(
    avg = sum(Complexity * duration) / sum(duration)
  )
```